# Can I have more than one index on a database table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have an existing Index on a database table, and I am new to Indexing.

I want to place a Clustered Index on a UniqueID column (the auto-increment column) as there is a lot of data.

Is it okay to have a second index on the table?

Existing Index is on a One To Many Value:

```
USE [Archive]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_CustomerWidget]    Script Date: 07/22/2014 16:27:32 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CustomerWidget] ON [dbo].[CustomerWidget] 
(
    [WidgetID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Also is there any harm in adding an Index - meaning if it is not right it can be dropped with no harm to the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is perfectly normal to have a clustered index (the order the data is on disk) and non-clustered indexes to support the queries that are executed against the database, or to enforce unquieness of a column.

For example I might have clustered index on the `IdentityID`, and a non-clustered index on `Date` because all my queries look like this: `Where Date between @Start and @End`.

Comment: Since you bring up a range query on `Date`(`Where Date between @Start and @End`), would a clustered index on `Date` not be more appropriate

Comment: As with all indexing strategies it depends, is the table append only, do dates change, is data deleted. Picking the correct index for a table is a tricky business and can need a lot of thought about how it will be used. Different patterns how the data is inserted/updated/deleted versus how it is queried can all affect how effective the index is.

Comment: +1. I would add that the one potential harm is added overhead of maintaining the index when doing table updates.  And the disk space the index will use. And potential blocking while it is being created.